# Markers not showing in Google Street View until the camera moves

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Markers are not displaying in the Google Maps Street View panorama the first time Street View mode is activated, until the camera is moved (change of location or pan around). Even [Google's own example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays) exhibits this behaviour in multiple browsers (FF, IE, Chrome) in the latest 3.31 API version and on several PCs and Chome on Android, so it looks like a bug.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Here's how to reproduce the behaviour:

1. Go to the ["Overlays within Street View" example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays).
2. Click the "Toggle Street View" button.
   [image: Toggle to streetview after page first loads]
3. Observe no pins present.
   [image: no pin present initially]
4. Move the camera slightly and see the coffee cup pin appear.
   [image: pin appears after first camera pan]

This is the code I'm using to switch to Street View:

```
var panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setPosition(<position>);
panorama.setPov(<pov>);
panorama.setVisible(true);
```

Some things that do work to show the markers:

- Using Pegman to switch to to street view
- Setting POV after a 1 second delay *sometimes* works

Once markers are displaying in Street View (eg using pegman or a camera move), they will continue to show, even when switching back and forth between map and streetview modes. If the page is refreshed, the no-show behaviour returns.

I've tried on a number of browsers, OSes, and hardware. If you're seeing different results to me, it would help if you could please post a comment on your broswer/OS/cpu?/graphics?.

Comment: I don't see the issue on Google's example (using Chrome).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (**in the question itself**)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip for checking. I wonder if it's specific to certain OSes or other factors? I've checked on Win7,8,10, private and corporate machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out [this is a bug in Street View, Google is aware of it, and there is a workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830290): call `setZoom(1)` before `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: Thank you! I've been scratching my head about this for an hour, trying to determine which `panorama` event to force-trigger -- similarly to `g.m.event.trigger(map, 'zoom_changed')` which tends to work for "stuck" map canvases...

Answer (score 0):

Setting the initial panorama `zoom` option helped me:

```
const panorama = map.getStreetView();

panorama.setOptions({
  ...
  zoom: 0,
});
```